# how to fix ubi-console-setup exit code 2 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, xubuntu

While trying to install ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop(actually, I have windows 8.1 installed already on my laptop and I want to install ubuntu along side it to make it 2 os), I run into this problem

> ubi-console-setup exit code 2 ubuntu 18.04

What are the causes and how can I fix the problem